# i'm trying to read 2 sets of data from a file and store them in respective arrays but it doesn't seem like the file is being read

Tags: java, file

i need to read a very large file for a project that has x and y values. i was given a file with the data and i need to read the values from it to do the necessary calculations. currently im just trying to read the data into 2 arrays and print it as i go just to confirm it's being read.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

class Main {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    File bean = new File("BeanDataset.txt");
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(bean);
    double[] minor = new double[13611];
    double[] major = new double[13611];
    Double num;
    int current = 0, minorcount=0, majorcount=0;

    while(scan.hasNextDouble()) {
      num = scan.nextDouble();

      if(current==0) {
        minor[minorcount] = num;
        minorcount++;
        current = 1;
      }
      else {
        major[majorcount] = num;
        majorcount++;
        current = 0;
      }
      System.out.println(num);
    }
  }
}
```

this is the first 20 lines of the data (the file is 267 pages long with 13611 entries) where the numbers alternate between minor and major

173.888747,      208.1781167
182.7344194,     200.5247957
175.9311426,     212.8261299
182.5165157,     210.557999
190.2792788,     201.8478822
181.5101816,     212.5605564
184.0390501,     211.0501553
182.7372038,     212.9967551
183.1571463,     213.5341452
180.8974686,     217.2278128
184.4398709,     213.5600894
188.3268476,     210.4862549
184.9692526,     214.6485485
183.6443122,     216.4848362
187.1929601,     212.0669751
186.5620882,     212.9759252
184.4716842,     215.6406947
184.8748759,     215.067737
187.535939,      212.4503189

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger. That will allow you to either fix the problem or edit your question to explain what's going wrong.

Comment: You certainly need to go past those strings and *then* start collecting double values. I would probably not use parallel arrays though

Comment: What is the problem exactly ? What error does your console shows ? Did you try to add a separator for your scanner ?

Comment: Your question is mutating ;) Now we see it's CSV-like...

Comment: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(bean).useDelimiter("\\s*,\\s*");while(scan.hasNextDouble()) { coordinatesList.add(new Coordinates(scan.nextDouble(), scan.nextDouble()); }` is the sort of thing you should probably be doing

Comment: `Scanner scan = new Scanner(bean).useDelimiter(",\\s+|\\s+");`. Don't forget to close your reader (`scan`).

Comment: Quite right. Try-with-resources is your friend